# Compress files using SSIS Process Task

Tags: ssis, compression, control-flow

I am trying to zip excel files using SSIS Process Task. This task asks for Executable. Unfortunately on the machine where I am executing SSIS, does not have any 3rd party provided compression utility. All I have is Windows built in compressor. I want to know how this can be used as executable and zip my files.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 7zip's command line version without installing it.

http://www.7-zip.org/download.html

Also, if your excel files are outputed as '.xlsx' they are already compressed.  This is also true for any other office type that ends in an 'x'.  Try changing the extension to '.zip' and open them.

Edit: Depending on how much you're doing you might want to consider buying the Cozyroc package which includes a zip task as well as many other useful ones.  Not too costly either.

http://cozyroc.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The link which you provided asks to download which is not possible in the client machine. Along with compress I need to zip the files too. Put all the excels in a single folder and zip them. Can I use built in Windows tool for this ?

Comment: you may need a script task for that, there are different options depending on your .NET framework. This is a good discussion about it:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8cdefd29-4f5c-4ec7-9acf-bf58e6622b85/unzip-single-file-from-a-zip-file-using-native-net-code?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Here is a method using VBSCript which can probably be converted to .Net script or at the very least called on the command line. I can't beleive you're not allowed to download 7ZIP

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add this note about *cozyroc*

You can test and develop with the SSIS+ components for as long as needed to determine if the components are suitable for your needs.

When you run the SSIS package from the command line with DTEXEC or SQL Server Agent, the license verification code is activated.

If a license is not found, the package execution will fail, the first time it tries to use SSIS+ library component.